# Método dando erro ao retornar valor

Tags: java, arraylist

Estou com o seguinte erro:

> cannot find simbol.

Ele da no return do metodo, dei uma revisada em meu código e não consegui localizar nada errado.

Segue o código abaixo:

```
 public ArrayList<String> verificarUsuario(){

    try {
        FileInputStream arquivo = new FileInputStream(caminho+"\\administrador.txt");
        InputStreamReader entrada = new InputStreamReader(arquivo);
        BufferedReader ler = new BufferedReader(entrada);
        String linha; 
        ArrayList<String>dados = new ArrayList<String>();
        do{
            linha = ler.readLine(); 

             if(linha!=null){
                 String[]palavra = linha.split(";");

                    for(int i =0;i<palavra.length;i++){
                      dados.add(palavra[i]); 

                   }
            }
       }
       while(linha!=null);

         arquivo.close();


    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro: Arquivo não encontrado!");
    }catch(IOException err){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro: "+err.getMessage());
    }        

     return dados;
}
```

Comment: Coloque um espaço entre `ArrayList<String>` e `dados`, veja se funciona.

Comment: Jovem, vou te dar umas dicas para escrever uma pergunta: **1**. Tente colocar um título que dê uma explicação sobre o seu problema, nada tão abstrato; **2**. Não esqueça de nos informar qual a linguagem; **3**. Explique melhor seu problema, com calma. Você sempre pode melhorar sua publicação clicando em [edit]

Comment: Consegui resolver aqui já, eu usei a correção do Netbeans que pedia para criar o campo dados na classe.